# Maximum number of CUDA blocks?

Tags: cuda

I want to implement an algorithm in CUDA that takes an input of size N and uses N^2 threads to execute it (this is the way the particular algorithm words). I've been asked to make a program that can handle up to N = 2^10. I think for my system a given thread block can have up to 512 threads, but for N = 2^10, having N^2 threads would mean having N^2 / 512 = 2^20 / 512 blocks. I read at this link (http://www.ce.jhu.edu/dalrymple/classes/602/Class10.pdf) that you the number of blocks "can be as large as 65,535 (or larger 2^31 - 1)".

**My questions are:**

**1)** How do I find the actual maximum number of blocks? I'm not sure what the quote ^^ meant when it said "65,535 (or larger 2^31 - 1)", because those are obviously very different numbers.

**2)** Is it possible to run an algorithm that requires 2^20 / 512 threads?

**3)** If the number of threads that I need (2^20 / 512) is greater than what CUDA can provide, what happens? Does it just fill all the available threads, and then re-assign those threads to the additional waiting tasks once they're done computing?

**4)** If I want to use the maximum number of threads in each block, should I just set the number of threads to 512 like `<<<number, 512>>>`, or is there an advantage to using a `dim3` value?

If you can provide any insight into any of these ^^ questions, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How do I find the actual maximum number of blocks? I'm not sure what the quote ^^ meant when it said "65,535 (or larger 2^31 - 1)",
>      because those are obviously very different numbers.

Read the relevant [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities), or build and run the [devicequery](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query) utility. But in either case, the limit is much larger than 2048 (which is what 2^20 / 512 equals). Note also that the block size limit on all currently supported hardware is 1024 threads per block, not 512, so you might need as few as 1024 blocks.

> 2. Is it possible to run an algorithm that requires 2^20 / 512 threads[sic]?

Yes

> 3. If the number of threads[sic] that I need .... is greater than what CUDA can provide, what happens?

Nothing. A runtime error is emitted.

> 4. Does it just fill all the available threads, and then re-assign those threads to the additional waiting tasks once they're done computing?

No. You would have to explicitly implement such a scheme yourself.

> 5. If I want to use the maximum number of threads in each block, should I just set the number of threads to 512 like `<<<number, 512>>>`, or is there an advantage to using a dim3 value?

There is no difference.